# SonarQube - Java Heap Error

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have several modules that do not contain source code in a maven multimodule project. When SonarQube analyses these modules, it would pause and give out the following warning :

```
Load module settings
00:40:47.304 [WARN] [09:29:52.769] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 2,123ms last 8 cycles average is 265ms
00:41:54.102 [WARN] [09:31:02.653] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 5,194ms last 8 cycles average is 649ms
00:42:37.907 [WARN] [09:31:48.387] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 3,927ms last 8 cycles average is 616ms
00:44:41.930 [WARN] [09:33:55.362] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 6,855ms last 8 cycles average is 856ms
00:45:48.276 [WARN] [09:34:51.298] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 3,144ms last 8 cycles average is 524ms
00:47:10.063 [WARN] [09:36:20.541] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 7,876ms last 8 cycles average is 984ms
00:48:26.295 [WARN] [09:37:39.723] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 12,296ms last 8 cycles average is 1,537ms
00:48:30.084 [ERROR] Java heap space
```

Is this error occurring because there are no source code inside or is there a corrupt file in there? Here are the contents of one of those module that exhibit this error:

```
module_1/
  feature.xml
  build.properties
```

I know that there is an option to skip modules, but since I am using SonarQube 4.3.2, it is deprecated. Is there anyway to avoid those modules or perhaps another way to fix this error?

EDIT: I found out that this error is probably not caused by empty modules as it displays this error on even full modules. So therefore, it is probably something wrong with my MAVEN_OPTS confiuration. Here is my MAVEN_OPTS configuration: `-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1000m -Xms4096m`

This computer has 8 gb of Ram, so memory is not an issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like SonarQube was running - Java simply ran out of memory.  Increase the max heap size used in the JVM running Sonar.

Comment: I have done that and increased the 2gb and it is still failing.

Comment: @user944849 I increased the Xmx to 4096 mb. It is still having this error. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I doubt you need that much perm gen or memory, I've never had to use more than 1 gig even with large builds.  As you have it above, there is a typo in the MAVEN_OPTS configuration.  Make sure there is a space between the various options: `-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms1024m`.  If that doesn't help, try running Maven with -X to get debug output and see what value MAVEN_OPTS has.  Also, are you running SonarQube through Maven or Jenkins?

Comment: I am running Sonar on Jenkins using Sonar plugin. Since I am building a maven project, I am running Sonar off of maven instead of Sonar-runner. Also, the typo is my fault, I will edit that, the actual porject settings does not have any typos. Is the solution to simply increase Xmx amount? Because after a particular number of modules analyzed, SonarQube would get stuck at "Loading module settings" even though there was no hiccup whatsoever before. Also, the project I am analysing is around 800 mb, so maybe Findbugs require more memory.

Comment: Go into the Jenkins build config for the project.  Scroll down to the Sonar section and click the Advanced button.  Are the JVM memory settings showing in the MAVEN_OPTS box there?  If not, add them and see what you get.

Comment: Yes, that is where I set them. I got permission from the system admin to increase Xmx to 8gb, which should be more than enough. Is this strictly an issue with lack of memory? I'm afraid there might be something wrong with the build since I have never seen "Journal Flush Operation" errors before.

Comment: Ok, I have added -X switch and the part where SonarQube hangs, the output displays :"[DEBUG] [11:54:36.742] Updating semaphore batch-MyApplication-eclipse38-java7.group:parent:trunk" then it would go on and give me the "Journal Flush Operation" error.

Comment: If you've increased the memory that much and are still getting errors, then I agree there's probably another issue.  There is a memory leak or something.  At this point someone more familiar with Sonar probably needs to step in.  Maybe a question on the SonarQube user forum?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've posted a question on nabble, unforunately, it seems no one answers there.I will offer bounty for this question tomorrow. There are so many factors involved, I have no idea where to start looking for the sources of errors haha.

Comment: Increase maven mem size all you want, your still limited by the memory assigned to jenkins. The first thing you should do to test that, however, is run it from command line outside of jenkins. If it works, you know the problem is jenkins

Comment: @Cole9350 Thank you for that suggestion. I will ask the admin how much memory is assigned.

Comment: @Cole9350 I think you are right. I ran maven on another Jenkins set up on my computer and the build completes without a hitch. So it may be something up with the official Jenkins that my company uses.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors .. In %JENKINS_HOME% There is a jenkins.xml.. in arguements make sure `-Xmx256m` is being set. If the error persists change to `-Xmx512m` ... You shouldn't need that much though

Comment: Apparently the production Jenkins is running on the same memory as the Jenkins that worked. Although the production Jenkins uses a newer version. Maybe it could be compatibility issues between the newer Jenkins version and Sonar plugin. I don't think it is a memory issue now, as I have noticed that increasing Xmx allows the analyses to progress a bit further, but nevertheless, the memory usage rises exponentially after about 30 modules. Maybe there is a memory leak somewhere, if I do find it, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where it used to hung on Journal Flushing and ultimately timeout at whatever the value i set in Findbags Java default timeout in sonarqube.

I resolved this by using the following options while running the sonar maven command:- MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx4096m -XX:+UseSerialGC"

This has fixed the issue for me.

The post which helped me:- http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/SonarQube-terminates-at-quot-Journal-Flusher-quot-warning-and-heap-size-error-td5027066.html